# Anvil or by-pass pruner?

Tags: tools

I have a few potted plants, and plan on expanding with more different variety of plants. Not sure what kinds.

I am looking for good quality pruners that will be most suitable for my different kinds of needs. I heard that anvil and bypass pruners are great but caters to different needs. Anvil for dead branches/stems and by-pass for live/green branches/stems. However, I have no idea how to know which one is live or dead.

Some of the plants I have right now:

1. Rubber plant
2. Money plant
3. Weeping fig
4. Neem Plant
5. Lemon plant
6. tamarind plant.

I am on a tight budget and because this is my first time, I am reluctant to invest in two different kinds of pruners. Please suggest me some nice ones from amazon.in or simply guide me with what kind of pruners I should purchase for first time and what kind of branches/stems I can cut with it.

Place India.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bypass pruners have two sharp blades, like scissors (except that the blades are curved, so they don't slip off the branch you are cutting). Anvil pruners have one sharp blade that is pressed against a flat plate.

Anvil pruners can handle harder and thicker stems but cause more damage to soft stems.

Cheap bypass pruners soon become useless, because the blades will soon get bent or the pivot will come loose, and they won't cut anything cleanly.

If you mistreat cheap anvil pruners, they will still work in the sense that they will "sort of" cut things, so long as you don't mind the plant looking as if an animal chewed through it rather than you cut it cleanly.

If you are just starting, you want one good quality general purpose tool. I would get a bypass pruner from a well known brand name like Nikawi, Felco, Löwe, Bahco, Wilkinson, Spear & Jackson, etc. They are more expensive than cheap Chinese tools, but will last a lifetime if you look after them.

(I know we are not supposed to make shopping recommendations but a list of half a dozen well known garden tool companies is not a recommendation for any particular tool, and I have no idea what is available in India or if there are any good-quality Indian tool companies.)

Don't buy *more* tools until you *know* what you want to use them for - i.e. you want to do something but the tools you already have can't do the job.

Comment: Thank you! Bypass pruner is what I am getting. None of these brands are available. I have only wolf-garten, sharpex and Falcon (no felco here).